# Get a List of File Names with a Specific Extension

Tags: excel, vba

I want a list of file names with a specific extension.

I am using this guide: https://trumpexcel.com/list-of-file-names-from-a-folder-in-excel/

The code doesn't return any values.

I entered the formula and it seems to return the value, however, it results in an error. I removed the IfError to test if it is even working. See screenshot:

[image: [Evaluate formula error screenshot]

With the full formula used together with IfError, nothing gets called out, which is not supposed to happen:

Full formula returns nothing
[image: [Full formula returns nothing screenshot]

```
Function GetFileNamesbyExt(ByVal FolderPath As String, FileExt As String) As Variant

Dim Result As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyFile As Object
Dim MyFSO As Object
Dim MyFolder As Object
Dim MyFiles As Object

Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files
ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.Count)
i = 1

For Each MyFile In MyFiles
    If InStr(1, MyFile.Name, FileExt) <> 0 Then
        Result(i) = MyFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next MyFile

ReDim Preserve Result(1 To i - 1)
GetFileNamesbyExt = Result

End Function
```

Comment: You are using `ROW()-2` in the formula, so you want to get 45th element of 3-element array. Use `ROW(A1)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice - I managed to solve this:)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue. Turns out that my Row() portion is wrong.

Because I am putting the formula in Row 47, my formula should have been:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(GetFileNamesbyExt($CK$44,$CK$45),ROW()-46),"")
```

Many thanks all!